# Можно добиться чтобы работала в Mozzila Firefox анимация фона с background-clip: text?

Tags: html, css, css-animation

Пример на codepen https://codepen.io/fess901/pen/rNWyqbK 
В Хроме работает нормально, фон показывается и анимируется внутри текста не выходя за его границы. 
В Мозиле просто выставление фона внутри текста работает нормально, но при попытке его анимировать, как в моем случае изменить позиционирование фона, все ломается и исчезает обрезка по границе текста.

Есть ли возможность как то заставить работать мой пример в браузере Mozzila Firefox?

**HTML**

```
<div class="test-class" style="background-image: url(https://st.depositphotos.com/2420147/2656/i/600/depositphotos_26569863-stock-photo-abstract-black-background.jpg);">Lorem</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.test-class{
font-weight: 900;
font-size: 440px;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-align: center;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: calc(50%) calc(50%);
-webkit-background-clip: text;
background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
-moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
text-fill-color: transparent;
pointer-events: none;
position: absolute;
bottom: -20px;
z-index: 1;
width: 100%;
-webkit-transition: 2s background-image;
transition: 2s background-image;
-webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
animation-duration: 2s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-delay: .5s;
animation-delay: .5s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-name: text;
animation-name: text;
```

}

@keyframes text {
0% {
background-position: calc(50%) calc(50%);
}
100% {
background-position: calc(50% - 40px) calc(50% + 60px);
}
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.test-class {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  z-index: 1;
  min-width: 100%;
  font-size: 440px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: calc(50%) calc(50%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  text-fill-color: transparent;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 2s background-image;
  animation: text 2s linear .5s forwards infinite;
}

@keyframes text {
  0% { background-position: calc(50%) calc(50%); }
  100% { background-position: calc(50% - 40px) calc(50% + 60px); }
}
```

```html
<div class="test-class" style="background-image: url(https://st.depositphotos.com/2420147/2656/i/600/depositphotos_26569863-stock-photo-abstract-black-background.jpg);">Lorem</div>
```